# Python: how to find all connected pixels if I know an origin pixel's position?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a binary image: `numpy.ndarray(dtype=bool)`. It has a few hundreds of connected regions filled with `True` value.

But I'm interested only in one region. I know the posision of one of its elements and want to find out the bounding box of this region-of-interest (and maybe the positions of other points of this region too).

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the size of your image it might be simplest to label the image to get **all** the connected components. Use the label of the known pixel to get the connected pixels as well. `skimage` makes this really simple using [`skimage.measure.label`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) and [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops). Be sure to understand the `connectivity` or `neighbors` parameter to `label`, as it affects whether diagonal neighbors touch or not.

```
from skimage import measure
import numpy as np

# load array; arr = np.ndarray(...)
# arr = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=bool)
# arr[:2,:2] = True
# arr[-4:,-4:] = True

labeled = measure.label(arr, background=False, connectivity=2)
label = labeled[8,8] # known pixel location

rp = measure.regionprops(labeled)
props = rp[label - 1] # background is labeled 0, not in rp

props.bbox # (min_row, min_col, max_row, max_col)
props.image # array matching the bbox sub-image
props.coordinates # list of (row,col) pixel indices
```